Any possible approach to avoid "circuit_breaking_exception" error, when fetching Elasticsearch Index with ES-Hadoop
Currently we are experiencing unresolvable data fetching issue regarding to Elasticsearch.
As a batch job, we use EsHadoop to fetch data from ES indexes.
Each ES index creates at a daily basis, namely log-22-YYYYMMDD.
Since each index has huge volume size of about 500GB, we create 24 external Hive tables as below:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MYDATA.ES_DATA_EXT (
.... column definition here ....
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsSerDe'
STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'es.reource'           = 'log-22-YYYYMMDD'
, 'es.nodes'             = 'x.x.x.x:9200,y.y.y.y:9200'
, 'es.mapping.date.rich' = 'false'
, 'es query'             = '{ \"query\" : { \"range : { \"reg_date\" : { \"gte\" : \"2024-06-27 23:00:00\", \"le\" : \"2024-06-28 00:00:00\" } } } }'
, 'exernal.table.purge'  = 'true'
);

When trying to load into a managed table from the above external table using
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE MYDATA.ES_DATA
SELECT * FROM MYDATA.ES_DATA_EXT;

Hive returns the following errors (in short):
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: circuit_breaking_exception: [parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [31759382830/29.5gb], which is larger than the limit of [31621696716/29.4gb], real usage: [31759382072/29.5gb], new bytes reserved: [758/758b], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=1184131672/1.1gb], in_flight_requests=758/758b, accounting=378111740/360.5mb]
{"query":{"range":{"reg_date":{"gte":"2024-06-27 23:00:00","lt":"2024-06-28 00:00:00"}}}, "_source":["flt1",........,"str9"]}
     at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.checkResponse(RestClient.java:477)
     at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:434)
     at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:428)
     at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:408)
     at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.scroll(RestRespository.java:311)
     at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.ScrollQuery.hasNext(ScrollQuery.java:93)
     at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormatEsInputRecordReader.next(EsInputFormat.java:255)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecoredReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:365)
     ... 24 more
]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:15, Vertex vertex_1716617651513_108904_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:............................

We googled for the error keyword and mostly it indicated to increase the Heap size to around 32gb, but we already set it to the maximum value.
As mentioned earlier, we try to fetch sub-partition from ES Index for each day. In other words, we create one external table for each an-hour data from ES Index.
The almost errors mostly happened when trying to fetch data between 23:00 and midnight. At the daytime, there's no error at all. This batch job runs at 00:30.
Can you provide any possible clue for this issue to fix?
(June 28, 2024) A batch job to fetch data between 23:00 and midnight begins at 00:30, which is heavily using with new ES Index for next day. As a result, ES index for batch job is not changeable.

Have you tried to reduce the interval to 30 min and fetch every 30 min?

@imotov Yes, I did try it. Once the above errors shows up, every executions return the same error, even though the time interval shrinks to 1 minutes: 23:00 ~ 23:01. No difference!!

My guess would be that something happens at 23:00 that generates a huge records in elasticsearch or a large number of records. I would try investigating this by running a histogram to rule out a large number of records and try retrieving records for that time period and just looking at them to see if they are different from other records.
